# Only get rows until qty total is met

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have an order table (product, qty_required) and a stock/bin location table (product, bin_location, qty_free) which is a one->many (a product may be stored in multiple bins).
Please, please (pretty please!) Does anybody know how to:
When producing a picking report, I only want to return the first x bins for each product ordered THAT SATISFIES the qty_required on the order.
For example
An order requires product 'ABC', QTY 10
Product 'ABC' is in the following locations (this is listed using FIFO rules so oldest first):
LOC1, 3 free
LOC2, 4 free
LOC3, 6 free
LOC4, 18 free
LOC5, 2 free

so. on the report, I'd ONLY want to see the first 3 locations, as the total of those (13) satisfies the order quantity of 10...
Ie:
LOC1, 3
LOC2, 4
LOC3, 6

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in the question.

Comment: Gosh ! Thanks for replying Gordon - I couldn't even manage a carriage return in my post ! I will try and do as requested (albeit i've just googled 'stack overflow text table in post' without too much joy already!)

Comment: @MarkTotnes Just insert text indented with spaces in `code` mode. It uses `monospaced` font

Comment: Thanks Gordon - i'll give that a bash....

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum(qty_free) over(partition by product order by placement_date desc, bin_location)` to calculate running sum and filter rows by your threshold in outer query (`select from select`). Added location in order by to exclude sum of all locations where placement was in the same day.

```
with s as (
  select st.*,
    sum(qty_free) over(partition by product order by placement_date asc, bin_location) as rsum
  from stock st
)
select
  o.product,
  s.bin_location,
  s.qty_free,
  o.qty_requested
from orders o
  left join s
    on o.product = s.product
      and s.rsum <= o.qty_requested
```

**UPD**: Since that turned out that your SQL Server version is so old that there's no analytic function in it, here's another less performant way to do this (maybe need some fixes, didn't tested on real data).
And [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5180c988a016cf3e1fea9cf661f19bed) with some setup.

```
with ord_key as (
  select stock.*,
    /*Generate order key for FIFO*/
    row_number() over(order by
      placement_date desc,
      bin_location asc
    ) as sort_order_key
  from stock
)
, rsum as (
  /*Calculate sum of all the items before current*/
  select
    b.product,
    b.bin_location,
    b.placement_date,
    b.qty_free,
    coalesce(sum(sub.item_sum), 0) as rsum
  from ord_key as b
    left join (
      /*Group by partition key and orderby key*/
      select
        product,
        sort_order_key,
        sum(qty_free) as item_sum
      from ord_key
      group by 
        product,
        sort_order_key
    ) as sub
      on b.product = sub.product
        and b.sort_order_key > sub.sort_order_key
  group by
    b.product,
    b.bin_location,
    b.placement_date,
    b.qty_free
)
, calc_quantities as (
  select
    o.product,
    s.placement_date,
    s.bin_location,
    s.qty_free,
    s.rsum,
    o.qty_requested,
    case
      when o.qty_requested > s.rsum + s.qty_free
      then s.qty_free
      else s.rsum + s.qty_free - o.qty_requested
    end as qty_to_retrieve
  from orders o
    left join rsum s
      on o.product = s.product
        and s.rsum < o.qty_requested
)
select
  s.*,
  qty_free - qty_to_retrieve as stock_left
from calc_quantities s
order by
  product,
  placement_date desc,
  bin_location desc
```

Comment: :) I'm excited, have copied, and am about to try... !

Comment: astentx ! Guess what ?! It transpires the server we are running is SQL 2005 (wow!) which in turn looks like it doesn't fully support the over (partion....) fully ! It returns "Incorrect syntax near 'order'.". I suspect the order by bit wasn't rolled out into the partition stuff until later versions :( PS - I've obviously checked and double-checked the syntax. Anyways, I still thank you for your reply/solution !

Comment: @MarkTotnes Oh, so old... As a workaround of that problem you may execute scalar subquery in `select` list or join with some date-generator on `less than or equal` condition. I will update my answer.